# Python, Referencing child attributes and methods in base class (and vice versa) there has to be a better way

Tags: python, class, inheritance, structure, radix

I have a base class that is inherited by multiple child classes.  This base class has a method, calc_func(self), which uses uniformly named methods, func(self), in the child classes.  This works but this 'architecture' would be very hard to follow if the code ever grew more complex.

```
# Base class
class base():
    x = 12  
    def calc_func(self):
        for i in range(1,4):
            self.y += self.func() 
            # neither y nor func() are defined here so
            # it is hard to know where they came from


# Child class 1
class child1(base):
    y = 10
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def func(self):   # method used in base class
        self.x += self.y
        print self.x
        return self.x
        # x was not defined here so it is
        # hard to know where it came from

# Child class 2
class child2(base):
    y = 15
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def func(self):   # method used in base class
        self.x *= self.y
        print self.x
        return self.x
        # x was not defined here so it is
        # hard to know where it came from

test1 = child1()  # Create object
test1.calc_func() # Run method inherited from base class


test2 = child2()  # Create another object
test2.calc_func() # Run method inherited from base class
```

The idea was to abstract out common code to the base class but this doesn't seem to be the right way of doing it.  Maybe this could be made more understandable by using a naming convention for methods and attributes which reference their particular class of origin?  Maybe a different architecture altogether?  Any advise will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could make the `Base` class abstract using `abc.ABCMeta` metaclass, then implement `func` in the `Base` class and mark it with an `@abstractmethod`. Alternatively simply putting a `def func(self): raise NotImplementedError()` in the base class can provide some clue about where `func` came from. In this way you can also add some documentation to the abstract `func` stating the properties it should have, so that users can safely derive that class and implement the functionality correctly.

Comment: It's really just a question of documenting what those called methods are. That's the advantage of abstract methods, you can add a doc string and it shows in the base and non-overriden subclasses telling implementers what's going on.

Comment: Thanks, I will give those suggestions a try

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This base class has a method, calc_func(self), which uses uniformly named methods, func(self), in the child classes. This works but this 'architecture' would be very hard to follow if the code ever grew more complex.

No, that's exactly how object-oriented polymorphism is supposed to work. You're already doing it right!

You say that this seems difficult to understand, but it's not clear why you think it's difficult. Probably the only thing you could do is (a) mark the base class as [abstract](http://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta) (b) have all methods that child classes are supposed to supply exist on the base class, but only have them raise `NotImplementedError`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I thought that if the base and child classes get to be hundreds of lines long and you throw in multiple inheritance then you could end up with a spiderweb of relationships between base and child classes that could present quite a challenge to debug.  That being said I will try your suggestion.  In point (b) did you mean: have all the methods that the CHILD classes are supposed to supply exist on the base class...?

Comment: @user2923409 Yes, that's an error in my answer. Your base classes should not be hundreds of lines long; and even if the methods in your child classes are very long, it doesn't matter. The complexity comes from having hundreds of methods, which you should probably avoid.